# Vim LaTeX-suite: EFI macro expand differently

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I an learning LaTeX-suite, and I found that the EFI macro for figure environment performance differently for different documents. Sometimes the image file line would be

```
\psfig{figure=<+eps file+>}
```

and sometimes it would be

```
\includegraphics{<+file+>}
```

This two kind of expansions seems happen randomly, since every time I just start a new empty article document. I think for the 'psfig' one the LaTeX-suite assume I am creating a `.dvi` file, but I was using `pdfLaTeX` all the time.
How the LaTeX-suite decide which expansion would be used in a specific document?

Comment: I know nothing about vim but you shouldn't use `\psfig` in any document written after about 1994, just use `\includegraphics`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I never use this so I'm confused why LaTeX-suite generate this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like `\psfig` is being used if the `graphicx` package (or I guess equivalent) has not been loaded, this way (in principle) the inserted environment can  be guaranteed to compile.  However on my machine at least it seems to miss when a package called in the main document (or at least an own package) in turn calls `graphicx`.

To always get `\includegraphics` defining `g:Tex_Env_figure` according to

```
let g:Tex_Env_figure="\\begin{figure}[<+htpb+>]\<cr>\\centering\<cr>\\includegraphics{<+file+>}\<cr>\\caption{<+caption text+>}\<cr>\\label{fig:<+label+>}\<cr>\\end{figure}<++>"
```

should produce `\includegraphics` when the figure environment is called (whether via `EFI` or <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

I keep running into this problem too. It appears that vim-latex is supposed to automatically detect which graphics package you're using, but this fails sometimes (in my case, I guess because I load graphicx in a different file).

The correct solution is to just let latex-vim know what package you want to use with:
`let g:Tex_package_detected = 'graphicx'` (issue in command mode, put in vimrc, or whatever)

Or add

```
if !exists("g:Tex_package_detected")
    let g:Tex_package_detected = 'graphicx'
elseif g:Tex_package_detected !~ '\<graphicx\>'
    let g:Tex_package_detected = g:Tex_package_detected.',graphicx'
endif
```

to `.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`

Or you can hardcode the figure macro yourself, as suggested in Dai Bowen's answer. Here's the manual for that: Manual: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#customizing-macros

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/vim-latex-devel/thread/1373471802.4529.1.camel@roddur/